# How do I scrape a Twitter list using snscrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to scrape tweets from this link https://twitter.com/i/lists/777955586638053376 using `snscrape`

I have tried using this till now:

```
from snscrape.modules.twitter import *
```

```
search = TwitterListPostsScraper("Abgeordnetenhaus #agh").get_items()
for item in search:
    print(item)
```

```
search = TwitterListPostsScraper("https://twitter.com/i/lists/777955586638053376").get_items()
for item in search:
    print(item)
```

```
search = TwitterListPostsScraper("777955586638053376").get_items()
for item in search:
    print(item)
```

every time, I got this error

```
Error retrieving https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=list%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fi%2Flists%2F777955586638053376&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo: 
non-200 status code
4 requests to https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json?include_profile_interstitial_type=1&include_blocking=1&include_blocked_by=1&include_followed_by=1&include_want_retweets=1&include_mute_edge=1&include_can_dm=1&include_can_media_tag=1&include_ext_has_nft_avatar=1&skip_status=1&cards_platform=Web-12&include_cards=1&include_ext_alt_text=true&include_quote_count=true&include_reply_count=1&tweet_mode=extended&include_entities=true&include_user_entities=true&include_ext_media_color=true&include_ext_media_availability=true&include_ext_sensitive_media_warning=true&include_ext_trusted_friends_metadata=true&send_error_codes=true&simple_quoted_tweet=true&q=list%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fi%2Flists%2F777955586638053376&tweet_search_mode=live&count=20&query_source=spelling_expansion_revert_click&pc=1&spelling_corrections=1&ext=mediaStats%2ChighlightedLabel%2ChasNftAvatar%2CvoiceInfo%2Cenrichments%2CsuperFollowMetadata%2CunmentionInfo 
failed, giving up.
```

What else can I do here?

EDIT:
updating the module fixed the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I review the [code in github from the project](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/blob/master/snscrape/modules/twitter.py#L1851) and it should work with the list number:

```
from snscrape.modules.twitter import *

search = TwitterListPostsScraper("777955586638053376").get_items()
for item in search:
    print({
        "tweet": item.rawContent,
        "url": item.url,
    })
```

It works perfectly for me, with the following results:

```
{'tweet': '@hardysee \U0001fae2☺️', 'url': 'https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620173624295718912'}
{'tweet': '@N_Stansfield Nee geht ja schließlich um die direkte Zufahrt in die Tiefgarage ?', 'url': 'https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620173294589853702'}
{'tweet': '@rainerschund Hab ich in den letzten Tagen viermal geschafft. Macht 60 Jahre mehr.', 'url': 'https://twitter.com/Dennis_Buchner/status/1620171154454646784'}
{'tweet': '@LiffKiff Das ist sehr schade. Aber bitte schau dir genau an, was die Berliner LINKE vorhat &amp; welche Positionen sie in der Frage bezieht. Abgesehen davon geht es bei der Berlin-Wahl ja um Berlin-Themen.', 'url': 'https://twitter.com/NiklasSchenker/status/1620170967132835843'}
...
```

Also I tried to replicate the behavior with the commandline and it also works:

```
snscrape twitter-list-posts 777955586638053376
https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620173624295718912
https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620173294589853702
https://twitter.com/Dennis_Buchner/status/1620171154454646784
https://twitter.com/NiklasSchenker/status/1620170967132835843
https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620167590545956868
https://twitter.com/Katina_Schubert/status/1620163364700962817
https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620163262179610624
https://twitter.com/klauslederer/status/1620162450489499649
https://twitter.com/klauslederer/status/1620162398517891073
https://twitter.com/klauslederer/status/1620162363470274560
https://twitter.com/Tobias_Schulze/status/1620161108320608256
https://twitter.com/Dennis_Buchner/status/1620159486278369280
https://twitter.com/NiklasSchenker/status/1620159380875517952
https://twitter.com/Dennis_Buchner/status/1620158807824543746
https://twitter.com/FrankHansel/status/1620151106457473027
```

However, in the code appears that you can also scrape lists using username/list:

```
        subparser.add_argument('list', type = snscrape.base.nonempty_string('list'), help = 'A Twitter list ID or a string of the form "username/listname" (replace spaces with dashes)')
```

So in this case it should be `snscrape twitter-list-posts wahl_beobachter/Abgeordnetenhaus-#agh` but when tried to do that I obtain an error.

If you want to test other scraping tools or scale your project you can consider using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to crawl these data and also run the crawler on the cloud using [estela](https://estela.bitmaker.la/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do by `TwitterSearchScraper()` with `list` parameter.

This code will works

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import pandas as pd

query = 'list:777955586638053376'   # list name is 'Abgeordnetenhaus #agh'
limit = 1000

tweets = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','URL' ,'Tweet'])

for index, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items()):
    if index > limit:
        break
    df2 = {'Date': tweet.date, 'URL': tweet.url, 'Tweet': tweet.rawContent}
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records([df2])])

print(df)

df.to_csv('list-tweets.csv')
```

Result

```
$ python3 get-list.py
                        Date                                                URL                                              Tweet
0  2023-01-30 21:10:29+00:00  https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/162016759...  @Engel_Re https:/x.xx/pWF6p6164g https://t.co...
0  2023-01-30 20:53:41+00:00  https://twitter.com/Katina_Schubert/status/162...  Vor 90 Jahren hat der damalige Reichspräsident...
0  2023-01-30 20:53:17+00:00  https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/162016326...  Angesichts der schon monothematischen Aktions-...
0  2023-01-30 20:50:04+00:00  https://twitter.com/klauslederer/status/162016...  Daseinsvorsorge in öffentlicher Hand, Hilfe fü...
0  2023-01-30 20:49:51+00:00  https://twitter.com/klauslederer/status/162016...  Aber ansonsten ging es um die Zukunft Berlins....
..                       ...                                                ...                                                ...
0  2023-01-25 07:51:55+00:00  https://twitter.com/BMJotzo/status/16181546836...  @AGhostOfNobody Okay, dann verstehe ich deinen...
0  2023-01-25 07:46:56+00:00  https://twitter.com/BMJotzo/status/16181534316...  @SNoleppa @josefheynckes Seit der Sperrung der...
0  2023-01-25 07:46:16+00:00  https://twitter.com/BerlinGestalter/status/161...  #Silvesterchaos, #Verkehrschaos, #Wahlchaos - ...
0  2023-01-25 07:44:19+00:00  https://twitter.com/SebCzaja/status/1618152774...  Unsere kaputte Verwaltung ist nicht nur ärgerl...
0  2023-01-25 07:42:39+00:00  https://twitter.com/GollalehA/status/161815235...  Nein, es ist ein Ruf nach Selbstverteidigung!\...

[1001 rows x 3 columns]
```

[image]

It matched tweet list items.

```
https://twitter.com/i/lists/777955586638053376
```

[image]

2nd Item in CVS

```
https://twitter.com/Katina_Schubert/status/1620163364700962817
```

[image]

3rd Item in CSV

```
https://twitter.com/kaddinsky/status/1620163262179610624
```

[image]

*First Item in CSV is retweet the 3rd item.